# Chrome ignores certificate pinning from extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a secure chrome extension that is supposed to safely connect to an **external https url that i do not own and that doesnt utilize certificate pinning itself**. Using HPKP, i want to pin the certificate in the browser extension to verify the host is legit.

I did some research where its claimed that this is [not possible](https://hackweek.suse.com/13/projects/850) apart from [calling chrome via command line](https://www.imperialviolet.org/2011/05/04/pinning.html). It was hard finding a lot of informations about HKPK for chrome (extensions)

Using webRequest & webRequestBlocking permissions i tried to intercept the response header. The theory is that if i can **add the HPKP header into the response header**, i can simulate the browser filtering future traffic from this header. I do this with the code below.

```
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(function(details) {
    //86400 = 1 day to prevent lockout on missing update
    var addHeader = [
        {name:"Public-Key-Pins", value:'max-age=30; pin-sha256="+sCGKoPvhK0bw4OcPAnWL7QYsM5wMe/mn1t8VYqY9mM="; pin-sha256="bumevWtKeyHRNs7ZXbyqVVVcbifEL8iDjAzPyQ60tBE="'},
        {name:"Strict-Transport-Security", value:"max-age=86400"}
    ];

    for(var i=0;i<details.responseHeaders;i++) {
        var existHeader = details.responseHeaders[i];
        for(var o=0;o<addHeader.length;o++) {
            var writeHeader = addHeader[o];
            if(existHeader.name.toLowerCase() == writeHeader.name.toLowerCase()) {
                details.responseHeaders[i].value = writeHeader.value;
                addHeader[o].written = true;
            }
        }
    }

    for(var i=0;i<addHeader.length;i++) {
        var writeHeader = addHeader[i];
        if(!writeHeader.hasOwnProperty("written")) details.responseHeaders.push({name:writeHeader.name, value:writeHeader.value});
    }

    return {responseHeaders: details.responseHeaders};
}, {urls: ["<all_urls>"]}, ["blocking","responseHeaders"]);

chrome.webRequest.onResponseStarted.addListener(function(details) {
    console.log(details);
}, {urls: ["<all_urls>"]}, ["responseHeaders"]);
```

The SHA256 hashes are random certificates found online, and when i call a website i expect the browser to block the request as long as its an https url (as RFC ignores http ones). Sadly, nothing happens at all, but the console returns that the data did get indeed attached.

**My question is**: Did i do something wrong at another place, or is there any other way to have my browser extension verify its talking to the correct host?

Comment: Looking at [source code](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/net/url_request/url_request_http_job.cc?sq=package:chromium&dr=Ss&rcl=1474903310&l=987) I think certificate checking (line 1020) isn't related to this event. Apparently it's a different path, not exposed to extensions. Hopefully, someone familiar with the internals can answer definitively.

Comment: I know that certificate checking is not part of it, thats why i try to fake the header in the first place. Of course it would be easier to access the certificate directly and compare a checksum.

Comment: What I meant is that source code doesn't seem to be using onHeaders path results in the onCertificate path.